# How to get image information (Image Name, Date, Time) from a specific album in Android

Tags: java, android, image, camera

First question I am posting here! I am having a tough time trying to figure this out. I am working with android devices and programming in android studio.

I came into this program half finished so I've been trying to complete it. The application takes a picture and does some analysis to it then stores it in an album (the album is called CameraSample). What I need to do is then put the information from the images in that album then into a list view in the application, note that the album size can continue to grow as the user takes the pictures.

I am pretty new to android development so i'm not sure what kind of commands I need to do in order to get this information from the pictures. What my predecessor before looked like they were trying to do was store the information into a database but it was left undone and sloppy. I'm not sure if that is the route I need to take or if there is possibly another way to get this information without using a database.

I've searched around online for awhile now but I'm having a tough time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do.

I had to create a database that when the picture was taken and the file was made where the picture was stored. I would record the uri, then also pass the immediate time and date to the database as well. From this I used the database to create a photo object array list and then used a custom adapter to fill in the row of each list for my view.